# "AttributeError: 'PythonTurtle' object has an invalid type 'bgcolor'"

Tags: python, attributeerror

I type in 'red' and I get this error:

```
Enter background color:  red
AttributeError: '<invalid type>' object has no attribute 'bgcolor' on line 14.
```

This is my code:

```
import turtle
#this asks the user to enter a colour
backcolor = input("Enter background colour: ")
#this is where Python actually sets the background colour
turtle.bgcolor(backcolor)

pencolor = input("Enter a pen colour: ")
turtle.color(pencolor)

turtle.pensize(5) 
count = 0

while (count < 20):
   turtle.forward(200)
   turtle.right(90)
   turtle.right(100)

   count = count + 1
```

What am I doing wrong please?  This works in Python IDLE

Comment: Try this `turtle.Screen().bgcolor(backcolor)`

Comment: What version are you using and what version in repl? Works perfectly fine for me with Python 3.9